# Adobe AIR locking

Tags: air, activation

I'm writing a program in Adobe AIR and need to lock it so that it only works on one computer per license bought.

I was originally planning on writing it myself and, with some great help from SO users in my last question, decided to make a call to an external program depending on the architecture and OS. However, due to time constraints - and a wish to easily keep the cross-platform advantage of AIR - I'm wondering whether there's a way to do it from within AIR such as a 3rd party library.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of researching this same thing for an AIR application, below are the service providers I am researching or have shortlisted:

- **www.activation-cloud.com/site/servicess**
- **www.digitaldeliveryapp.com**
- **www.payloadz.com**
- **www.sharify.it** - This has been in beta for 3 years and still is.
- **www.nitrolm.com** - This company focuses on renewable licenses and doesn't offer a solution for one-time or lifetime licenses.
- **www.zarqon.net**
- **www.wyday.com/limelm** - I'm heavily leaning towards this company, I am just not impressed with the screenshots of their Account Control panel.
- **www.sentinelcloud.com** - Extremely robust and offersNo pricing online.

Since it has been a while since you posted this question... please share anything you have learned or how you solved it.

Comment: I ended up making one myself because I couldn't find anything but it wasn't great. I'll post details if you like but if any of the ones you've listed works for you, I imagine it'll be considerably better.

Comment: can you post details on what you came up with?